# Win32 in C - Why does my text show up as a foreign language?

Tags: c, winapi, locale

Started looking at the win32 API on this site: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/start.html

I've literally just compiled the first example and it's given me a message prompt in chinese/japanese, or something along those lines.

Question: Why?

Obviously as far as my understanding goes, I should be getting "Goodbye, cruel world!" in a message box (Presumably titled 'Note').

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
MessageBox(NULL, "Goodbye, cruel world!", "Note", MB_OK);
return 0;
}
```

[image: Foreign...]

Thanks.

Comment: I am extremely terrified of Chinese people... and Chinese message boxes :D

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem.

Comment: You're using ANSI strings, but compiling for Unicode. Maybe that web site should have mentioned something about that...

Comment: See Tim Minchin's song called "Three Minute Song", he answers your question. For China! For China! For China! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58mE7Vy1Xrc

Comment: @Vlad No sound at work. :p Give me 3 hours!

Comment: I think this is the new autotranslate feature of Ms Visual Studio as 潇摯祢ⱥ挠畲汥眠牯摬! exactly means goodbye cruel world. Note the ⱥ which denotes the despair.

Comment: That shouldn't have compiled cleanly.  Turn on `STRICT`, and pay attention to warnings like "forcing `char*` to `const wchar_t*`".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to change the code like this:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
MessageBox(NULL, L"Goodbye, cruel world!", L"Note", MB_OK);
return 0;
}
```

If it works is because you are missing some header that point the correct API, you seem calling MessageBoxW ( the unicode version ) with an ANSI string. If this is not just a test but you are beginning to write a real world program, consider to ensure what kind of caracter you want to use ( this is a precompiler flag usually ). Then use the macro `_T(` to have your literals compatible both to unicode/ansi.

**Edit from @Benoit comment:** 
Starting a new project with VS 2008/10 sets unicode character set by default.

Comment: I would add: starting with Visual Studio 2008 (or maybe 2010) new projects use the Unicode character set by default.

Comment: Hardcoding Unicode strings is just as problematic as hardcoding ANSI strings.  Either respect the project-wide Unicode setting and use `_T("string")` or explicitly use the function that matches: `MessageBoxA` for ANSI and `MessageBoxW` for Unicode.

Answer (score 5):

```
MessageBox(NULL, _T("Goodbye, cruel world!"), _T("Note"), MB_OK);
```

or

```
MessageBoxA(NULL, "Goodbye, cruel world!", "Note", MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't get it set to default, so each new project it must be set.
To find the setting:
Using Visual Studio 2010
From the main Menu → Projects → Properties → Configuration Properties → General → Project Details → Character Set → "Use Multi-Byte Character set" (was set to "Use Unicode Character Set")

After that all seems well.